# Hide selection from iframe when blurred?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, selection

Is it possible to hide the selection of an iframe when it loses focus?

Example:

[image: selected text on iframe]

1. Select a text on a contentEditable iframe
2. Click out the iframe

Result: The selection is still visible (grayed)

Expected result: The text without the inactive selection style.

Is there some property, or some script to do it? (I do not want to lose the selection)

Comment: Do you have access to the JS code inside of the iframe?

Comment: @Blender yes, it is possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767037/editing-iframe-content-in-ie-problem-in-maintaining-text-selection/5770175#5770175 and the focus / blur bit at the bottom of my answer here should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470932/ie8-iframe-designmode-loses-selection/1471198#1471198

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an `onblur` event for your iframe:

```
window.onblur = function() {
  if (window.getSelection) {
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  } else if (document.selection) {
    document.selection.empty();
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, it removed the selection, but I lost it and `document.execCommand` became useless... I just wanted to show the real background color while the user selects it. With the selection style (this gray thing) the color is not the same as the user sees. I guess it is not possible then... Thanks...

Comment: It is on Webkit browsers (and Firefox, I think) via CSS3.